# mysql: take all records with meeting_id = x and it's parent is available but don't care if available itself?

Tags: sql, mysql

how do i select all records matching following criteria:

take all records with meeting_id = x AND it's parent is available OR doesn't have parent but don't care if available itself ?

```
table people:  
id, name, address, meeting_id, available, parent_id
```

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statement would help, rather than just a column list because the data types and optionality (NULL or NOT NULL) would help us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from people outt
  where meeting_id = x and
  (parent_id is null or exists (select 1 from people inn where inn.id = outt.parent_id and available = 1))
```

Comment: I am guessing that this query will be the faster than a join, but not particularly sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, pls try. If no parent coalesce will select second param and use automatic 1.

```
SELECT * FROM people 
  WHERE 
    meeting_id=x AND 
    ( COALESCE( (SELECT available FROM people AS parent WHERE id=parent_id), 1) )
```

Comment: I am assuming parent_id is nullable

Comment: yes it is nullable, and your query does the job. thanks, I will read more about coalesce

Answer (score 0):

You may do it using JOIN:

```
SELECT
  child.*,
  parent.name
FROM
  people child
LEFT JOIN
  people parent on (child.parent_id = parent.id)
WHERE
  (parent.available = 1 or parent.id IS NULL) AND
  child.meeting_id = x;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html for details

Comment: child.available is not required, since it does not care if available itself.

Comment: Do you mean, "parent.id IS NULL" is not required?

Comment: Ah, got it at last. Fixed in answer.